# Reutilizar propiedades de layout android studio

Tags: android

Hay una forma para reutilizar propiedades para los diferentes componentes del layout, pero no recuerdo como se definían y se asignaban; ¿Alguien puede dejarme un ejemplo?

Por ejemplo, si tengo 15 TextView y le asigno a cada uno la propiedad `android:textSize="35sp"` no sale rentable, ya que luego si quiero cambiar el tamaño deberé modificar a todos manualmente, este método permitía reutilizar estas propiedades como si fueran una variable y luego asignarlas a elementos del layout. 
Recuerdo que se hacia dentro del mismo xml del layout y no en la parte "programatica".

Comment: Definiendo un estilo para tu TextView te ayudaria a cambiar sus propiedades dinamicamente. En la documentacion oficial hay muchos ejemplos: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

Comment: Gracias, no recordaba el nombre como para buscarlo :D!

Answer (score 0):

En styles.xml defines el conjunto de propiedades que quieras reutilizar:

```
<!-- Valor del resultado -->
<style name="cardTitleSize" parent="match_wrap">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTitle</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">9dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

y luego lo agregas en un elemento de la siguiente manera:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/ic_value"
     style="@style/cardTitleSize"
     android:text="@string/def"/>
```